# What is/how does the "search" command work?

Tags: linux, search, linux-mint

Put briefly, can I use the 'search' command to search through file contents? If so, how?

I am trying to find an easier way to search through file contents in Linux Mint than having to type

```
grep -rnw . -e 'my search text'
```

I just noticed there is a 'search' command

```
$ which search
/usr/local/bin/search
```

However, when I look at its help text; I am presented with this:

```
usage: search [arguments] [options]
arguments:
     for text
     in directory
```

I am unable to make sense of this, any arguments I try passing in seem to inevitably lead me to the same text.

There is also no man page entry, I tried that as well.

I have tried e.g.

```
$ search "my search text" .
$ search . "test"
$ search . . . .
```

Lacking a way to get this to work, I may opt for an alias. Sadly though, 'search' is already taken..

Comment: Check the manpage: man search

Comment: @Cyclonecode man page doesn't have an entry for the search command. Never mind, I'll just give up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just did a clean install, and went to have a look at this 'search' executable. Turns out, it is in fact a shell command with the following resulting command:

```
find $directory -type f -exec grep -$case$verbose "$text" --color=auto -n {} \;
```

The four $variables above are respectively populated with the search directory, case-sensitivity, verbosity and ultimately the single word search text.

I have no idea why this facility exists, but as the manual suggests, you can only use it to search for a single word (no spaces), and in the specified following directory.

An example looking for (case insensitive) and without verbosity would thus be:

```
search for bar in ~/home/foo
```

The command was apparently added in Linux mint in 2008, as indicated [in this post](https://blog.linuxmint.com/?p=346) that also details its use.

Answer (score -1):

Holy smokes. I never thought you may need to interpret a manual so literally;

```
$ search for text in directory
find: ‘directory’: No such file or directory
```

It still doesn't completely make me sure how to use it exactly, though; I am puzzled on whether it supports regex/wildcards, etc.

I do get good results for simple case-insensitive text with

```
~/mytargetfolder/ $ search for singlewordspacesdontwork in .
```

However, it breaks as soon as there is a space, escaping it with ", \  or ' is not working.

Given my experienced, I'd recommend steering clear of this command.

I'd also like to recommend not giving answers on StackOverflow, or asking questions like these, since I seem to be having a case of the downvotes as of just now?

Comment: I don't understand the downvote? Want negativity? This is how you get it. What else am I supposed to do? Not ask on Stackoverflow and seek help elsewhere? Or should I not attempt to answer? I am angry now.

Comment: Your answer doesn't actually, you know, answer anything. We can't know what put this command in your `/usr/local/bin` but the location suggests that something you did after installation placed it there. It's not part of the system you are asking about.

Comment: @tripleee 1) It doees answer how to use it(although not fully), secondly I just did a clean install of Linux mint 18.3 on my home PC, and the search executable is present there too.

Comment: Search can find a string if it is quoted. For example: search 'all done' displayed every occurence  of the phrase in the current directory.